# Check if charcter is included in a font

Tags: .net, unicode, fonts

How can I check if a weirdo character I'd like to use is included in the used font?

Answer (score 2):

Try using GetFontUnicodeRanges (from gdi32.dll), and then checking the GLYPHSET that is returned.

GetGlyphIndices is supposed to return 0xffff for non-existant glyphs (if called with the GGI_MARK_NONEXISTING_GLYPHS flag), but I've seen a [report that it is broken](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/2006-06/msg00081.html), so you should probably avoid it.